# How can I convert gaps in dates to discrete intervals?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena, presto

Can't think of a better title for this, and I've had a lot of problems coming up with a solution in SQL.

Basically, I have a table of events with dates and an associated entity, like the following:

| event | entity | date |
| --- | --- | --- |
| er_visit | bob | 2020-01-01 |
| triage | bob | 2020-01-01 |
| admitted_to_icu | bob | 2020-01-01 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 2020-01-02 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 2020-01-03 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 2020-01-03 |
| hospital_discharge | bob | 2020-01-11 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 2020-01-12 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 2020-01-13 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 2020-02-01 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 2021-02-11 |
| pregnancy_checkup | alice | 2020-01-01 |
| admitted_maternity_ward | alice | 2020-02-01 |
| inpatient_birth | alice | 2020-02-02 |
| bed_rest | alice | 2020-02-02 |
| bed_rest | alice | 2020-02-03 |
| bed_rest | alice | 2020-02-04 |
| hospital_discharge | alice | 2021-02-04 |

I need to turn this into a list of events per entity, with the relative dates encoded as discrete intervals - say 1 day, 1 week, 1 month, 1 year - and other intervals encoded as a combination of those intervals. 14 months, 15 days would be 1 year + 1 month + 1 month + 1 week + 1 week + 1 day.

| event | entity | seq |
| --- | --- | --- |
| er_visit | bob | 1 |
| triage | bob | 2 |
| admitted_to_icu | bob | 3 |
| nextday | bob | 4 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 5 |
| nextday | bob | 6 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 7 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 8 |
| nextweek | bob | 9 |
| nextday | bob | 10 |
| hospital_discharge | bob | 11 |
| nextday | bob | 12 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 13 |
| nextday | bob | 14 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 15 |
| nextweek | bob | 16 |
| nextweek | bob | 17 |
| nextday | bob | 18 |
| nextday | bob | 19 |
| nextday | bob | 20 |
| nextday | bob | 21 |
| nextday | bob | 22 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 23 |
| nextyear | bob | 24 |
| nextweek | bob | 25 |
| nextday | bob | 26 |
| nextday | bob | 27 |
| nextday | bob | 28 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 29 |
| pregnancy_checkup | alice | 1 |
| nextmonth | alice | 2 |
| admitted_maternity_ward | alice | 3 |
| nextday | alice | 4 |
| inpatient_birth | alice | 5 |
| bed_rest | alice | 6 |
| nextday | alice | 7 |
| bed_rest | alice | 8 |
| nextday | alice | 9 |
| bed_rest | alice | 10 |
| hospital_discharge | alice | 11 |

Is there a reasonable solution for this in Athena (Presto) SQL?

Comment: Start here: `date_diff('day', min(date) over (partition by entity), date) as duration`

Comment: Is the second table being the desired output, cause it kind of does not match the description?

Answer (score 0):

Done in Trino, but should be the same for these functions.

I've output the intervals in number of days, converting it from there to your strangely formatted desired output is possible, but way more complicated than makes sense.

```
WITH the_table AS (
    SELECT event, entity, date(date) date
    FROM (VALUES
          ('er_visit', 'bob', '2020-01-01'), ('triage', 'bob', '2020-01-01'),
          ('admitted_to_icu', 'bob', '2020-01-01'), ('inpatient_bed_rest', 'bob', '2020-01-02'),
          ('inpatient_bed_rest', 'bob', '2020-01-03'), ('physical_therapy', 'bob', '2020-01-03'),
          ('hospital_discharge', 'bob', '2020-01-11'), ('physical_therapy', 'bob', '2020-01-12'),
          ('physical_therapy', 'bob', '2020-01-13'), ('inpatient_followup', 'bob', '2020-02-01'),
          ('inpatient_followup', 'bob', '2021-02-11'), ('pregnancy_checkup', 'alice', '2020-01-01'),
          ('admitted_maternity_ward', 'alice', '2020-02-01'), ('inpatient_birth', 'alice', '2020-02-02'),
          ('bed_rest', 'alice', '2020-02-02'), ('bed_rest', 'alice', '2020-02-03'),
          ('bed_rest', 'alice', '2020-02-04'), ('hospital_discharge', 'alice', '2021-02-04'))
             AS data(event, entity, date)
)
SELECT event
     , entity
     , date_diff('day', lag(date) OVER (PARTITION BY entity ORDER BY date), date) days_since_last
FROM the_table
```

| event | entity | days_since_last |
| --- | --- | --- |
| pregnancy_checkup | alice | NULL |
| admitted_maternity_ward | alice | 31 |
| inpatient_birth | alice | 1 |
| bed_rest | alice | 0 |
| bed_rest | alice | 1 |
| bed_rest | alice | 1 |
| hospital_discharge | alice | 366 |
| er_visit | bob | NULL |
| triage | bob | 0 |
| admitted_to_icu | bob | 0 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 1 |
| inpatient_bed_rest | bob | 1 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 0 |
| hospital_discharge | bob | 8 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 1 |
| physical_therapy | bob | 1 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 19 |
| inpatient_followup | bob | 376 |